# Onde criar uma classe própria, e como instanciá-la depois?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, laravel-4, classes

Tenho uma classe própria (i.e. externa às bibliotecas padrão do PHP e do Laravel) que faz algumas conexões com equipamentos da minha rede e além disso preciso criar rotinas de notificações por e-mail e SMS.

Para referência, [esta é a classe](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/API_PHP_class):

```php
<?php
/*****************************
 *
 * RouterOS PHP API class v1.5
 * Author: Denis Basta
 * Contributors:
 *    Nick Barnes
 *    Ben Menking (ben [at] infotechsc [dot] com)
 *    Jeremy Jefferson (http://jeremyj.com)
 *    Cristian Deluxe (djcristiandeluxe [at] gmail [dot] com)
 *
 * http://www.mikrotik.com
 * http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/API_PHP_class
 *
 ******************************/

class routeros_api
{
    ...
}
?>
```

## Pergunta

Onde colocar os arquivos da classe, e como chamá-la depois a partir da aplicação?

E, se existe mais de uma opção viável, quais seriam as boas práticas *para manter organizado o código de terceiros*?

Comment: Não está claro o que você está perguntando. Você poderia por favor editar a pergunta e incluir mais detalhes? O que você já consegue fazer e o que falta? Em que pontos precisa de ajuda? Boas práticas em relação a quê? Como são essas classes que você já tem? Não existe uma resposta genérica, cada classe tem uma maneira diferente de usar. A dúvida é como integrar as classes no Laravel?

Comment: Tenho essa classe por exemplo:

http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/API_PHP_class

E preciso utilizar ela em um projeto que está sendo desenvolvido em laravel. A questão é, onde colocá-la e como utilizar.

Comment: @ElizandroPacheco na minha opinião, agora a pergunta já está "respondível". Pois se entendi bem, você quer saber em que parte da sua estrutura de pastas você deve colocar uma nova classe (sua ou de terceiros) de modo que o Laravel a encontre [e, se existir mais de uma opção, qual seria a mais apropriada], é isso? (P.S. vou tentar sugerir uma edição para melhorar **a forma** - sem mexer no **conteúdo**)

Comment: @Elizandro Pacheco seu problema é com o carregamento da classe? colocou a classe na pasta certa? o framework segue algum padrão de carregamento(PSR-)? descreva melhor o que vc já tentou.

Comment: @perdeu eu ainda não tentei nada, vim perguntar justamente pra começar da forma certa.

Comment: @mgibsonbr Exatamente isso!

Comment: @ElizandroPacheco Dá uma olhada nesse pacote, eu uso ele pra me comunicar com o RouterOS:
https://packagist.org/packages/pear2/net_routeros

dá pra instalar via composer então já estará carregado automaticamente

Comment: considera também a opções de usar package, dependendo do que tu ta fazendo pode ser a melhor solução e ainda pode reaproveitar em outros projetos.

Answer (score 9):

Eu normalmente crio uma pasta Library dentro de /app, e a adiciono no autoload do composer.json (nó autoload -> classmap)

Você pode ainda, adicionar no autoload do próprio Laravel, no arquivo /app/start/global.php

Link: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/start/global.php#L14

Note que ao optar pela segunda opção, não precisará rodar o dump-autoload do composer toda vez que criar uma classe, ou alterar o namespace e etc, ao contrário da primeira opção.

Ou ainda, pode criar um package e colocar suas classes na pasta vendor/

Como pode ver, o Laravel é muito flexível nessa parte, fica a seu próprio gosto, não existe uma "receita de bolo". O que eu posso considerar como "boa prática", para o seu projeto pode não se encaixar, então vai de suas necessidades.

PS: Ao criar subpastas, não se esqueça de utilizar os namespaces corretamente para o autoload funcionar.

Comment: Criei a pasta library e coloquei o arquivo ( routeros.php ) lá dentro.

O nome da classe é RouterOS dentro desse arquivo. Lá no start/global.php adicionei a pasta library mas quando tento instanciar a classe no controller e me retorna o seguinte erro:

Class 'RouterOS' not found

Comment: Lembre-se de colocar o nome da classe e arquivo de acordo com o padrão de autoload da PSR. Altere o nome do arquivo para RouterOS.php

Comment: Funcionou perfeito! Obrigado @Brayan

Comment: Se optar por colocar o classmap do composer você também pode editar ele manualmente para não precisar rodar um update toda vez que adicionar uma classe. O arquivo fica em `/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`

Answer (score 4):

#### Para código diretamente relacionado às regras de negócio da sua aplicação

Sinto muito dizer que o PSR-0 está sendo `substituído` pelo PSR-4, que torna a nossa vida muito mais fácil na hora de gerenciar diretórios de classes, à medida que ele não exige que você crie pastas com o nome do namespace, o que costumava ser confuso pra maioria que tentava começar a usar o PSR-0.

O PSR-4 está disponível para ser usado se seu Composer estiver atualizado:

```
[sudo] composer self-update
```

Assim sendo, aconselho que você use um padrão parecido com:

```
"autoload": {

    "psr-4": {
        "Empresa\\Pacote\\": "app/Pacote/"
    }
},
```

Feito isso você só precisa criar o arquivo `Classe.php` em:

`app/Pacote/Classe.php`

E não como acontecia no PSR-0, se você escrevesse igual, teria que colocar em:

`app/Pacote/Empresa/Pacote/Classe.php`

E seguir as regras normais de criação de namespace para as suas classes:

```
<?php 

namespace Empresa\Pacote;

class Classe extends Whatever {

}
```

Em seguida basta você atualizar os arquivos `autoloaders` do Composer:

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

E provavelmente ele terá criado o arquivo

```
vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php
```

Com uma linha apontando para a sua pasta, que será depois `vasculhada` caso o PHP precise carregar alguma das classes ali presentes.

#### Para código de terceiros o que você queira reutilizar

Quando se trata de código de terceiro ou código seu que poderá ser usado em mais de uma aplicação sua o ideal, no meu entender, é criar um pacote Composer.

Parece complicado, mas é bem simples, seguem os passos:

1) Crie um repositório para o seu pacote no github ou bitbucket.

2) Crie uma pasta em qualquer lugar, que ainda não precisa estar ligada ao seu aplicativo.

3) Nela crie um arquivo composer.json e nele você precisa basicamente ter:

```
{
    "name": "empresa/pacote",

    "description": "<descrição>",

    "keywords": ["palavra-chave1", "palavra-chave1"],

    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.7",
    },

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Empresa\\Pacote\\": "src/"
        }
    },

    "extra": {
            "component": "package",
            "frameworks": ["Laravel 4"],
            "versions": {
                    "0.8.0": "master"
            },
            "branch-alias": {
                    "dev-master": "0.8.0-dev"
            }
    },

    "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

3) Criar os arquivos fontes do pacote dentro da pasta `src/`. Este nome de pasta se tornou padrão, mas muita gente usa coisa diferente, como `lib/`.

4) Enviar o seu pacote para um repositório git:

```
git init
git remote add <repositorio>
git commit -m "mensagem"
git push origin master
```

5) E, finalmente, adicionar o pacote ao composer.json do seu projeto:

```
"require": {
    "empresa/pacote": "dev-master",
},
```

6) Como o seu pacote ainda não está publicado no Packagist, você vai precisar avisar ao Composer aonde estão os fontes dele, no caso se o seu VCS é o Github, você vai fazer:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url":  "https://github.com/seunome/pacote.git"
    }
],
```

7) E basta atualizar o composer para ver o seu novo pacote sendo baixado na sua aplicação:

```
composer update --prefer-source
```

Eu adicionei a opção `prefer-source` para que o composer baixe, além dos fontes, também o diretório `.git`, de maneira que você possa editar o seu pacote diretamente no diretório da sua aplicação e comitar as mudanças sem ter que sair dele.

Não sei se pareceu complicado, mas garanto que é bem fácil.

Comment: Beleza. Muito bom. Lá no começo, no teu primeiro exemplo, não seria `"psr-4":` ou invés de `"psr-0":`?

Comment: Sim, claro, eu falando em PSR-4 e acabei escrevendo 0...

Answer (score 2):

Com o Laravel e Composer fica muito fácil trabalhar com suas próprias classes.

Se você organizar bem suas classes com namespaces fica extremamente fácil de carrega-las depois

Eu faço assim:

> app/Meupacote/
>
> app/Meupacote/MinhaClasse.php

```php
namespace Meupacote;
class MinhaClasse{}
```

e no composer.json você facilmente as carrega:

```json
"autoload": {
    
    "psr-0": {
        "Meupacote": "app/"
    }
},
```

Você pode colocar toda a sua aplicação ali, como models e controllers

> app/Minhaapp/
>
> app/Minhaapp/Controllers/
>
> app/Minhaapp/Controllers/HomeController.php

```json
"autoload": {
        
        "psr-0": {
            "Minhaapp": "app/"
        }
    },
```

Lembre-se fazendo assim você deve passar a importar as outras classes já que agora você esta trabalhando com namespace

```php
namespace Minhaapp\Controllers;
use BaseController;
class HomeController extends BaseController{}
```

Não háverá dificuldades de se configurar suas rotas

```php
Route::get('/', 'Minhaapp\Controllers\HomeController@index');
```